# I have a set of values within a text file with delimiters how do I modify a value using C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, text-files

The text file that I have contains the below as the data (Starting with the K and D and P respectively as the ID)

K1234:Green_Book:A_green_book:10:
K3346:Red_Book:A_red_book:7:
D3333:Grey_Book:A_grey_book:15:
D1111:Black_Book:A_black_book:1:
P0000:White_Book:A_white_book:6:

what I would like to do is to modify the Data in the line that starts with D3333 and change the value from **15 to 17** in the text file. I really do not know how to do that as I am new to C programming and this has been troubling me for days now. I have tied searching all over the net but my searches were of no avail. If anyone can please help me with the code that can do that or something similar, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

This is what i have done so far:

```
void show(){
    FILE * fl;
    long fl_size;
    char * buffer;
    size_t res;

    fl = fopen("inventItems.txt", "r+");
    if (fl == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File error\n");
        _getch();
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_END);
    fl_size = ftell(fl);
    rewind(fl);

    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*fl_size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fputs("Memory error", stderr);
        _getch();
        exit(2);
    }

    res = fread(buffer, 1, fl_size, fl);
    if (res != fl_size) {
        fputs("Reading error", stderr);
        _getch();
        exit(3);
    }
    char * strtok_res;
    strtok_res = strtok(buffer, ":");
    while (strtok_res != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", strtok_res);//this prints the values from the file to a new line when i test it
        //however i DO NOT KNOW how to modify and save it back onto the text file
        strtok_res = strtok(NULL, ":");
        _getch();
    }
    _getch();
    fclose(fl);
    free(buffer);

}
```

Comment: Is this a programming problem that you are trying to solve in order to learn to program, or is this something you are trying to get done. What is special about the line that starts with 'D3333'. Are you trying to write code that can change the number on the end by selecting the first Number/letter combination?

Comment: This is a programming problem that im trying to learn how to solve. It is also something that I would like to get done because i feel that in C programming one of the most difficult parts I have come across is file manipulation. The 'D3333' is just an example of a line which has a value that I would like to change. To answer your question yes, I actually want to be able to change the end by selecting the first Number/letter combination

Comment: Ok. Have you made an attempt at all? Post what you have tried to do so far

Comment: the code has been added

Comment: do u know any source that can guide a person like me who is still relatively new to C programming?

Comment: @Don patience. I'm writing you a fairly detailed answer.

Comment: @BenWainwright Thanks. I shall be patient

Comment: If that helps, please accept the answer @Don

Answer (score 2):

Ok, looks like you are doing this along the right lines. A couple of comments:

## Repitition and Readability

You are repeating yourself a lot; variations on

```
if(whateverPointer == NULL) {
   fprintf("My error message", stderr);
   _getch();
   exit(2);
}
```

are used on three separate occasions; so should be moved into a separate function that takes a `char*` (string) message to pass into `fprintf()`, so that you can just do

```
if(whateverPointer == NULL) {
   errorThenDeath("My message", 2);
}
```

This might seem irrelavent to the question, but as well as being a good habit to get into, it will make your code easier to read. The easier your code is to read, the easier it is for other people to help you when you are stuck: *always remember this*.

On a similar veign, you have indicated that you want to use a specific identifier to change a specific line. With this in mind, you should be breaking your problem up to identify this specific problem, so the code that performs that particular task should be contained in a function that might have a signature like this.

```
int changeLineValue(char** buffer, size_t size, char* identifier, int newValue) 
{
...
}
```

Note the double pointer (`char**`) this is a pointer to the original `char*`. When inside this function, you can get at the original pointer by dereferencing it (`*`) so

```
*buffer = "hello";
```

Would change the buffer to the string 'hello'.

## The Problem

I'm not sure tokenising the buffer is the right approach. `strtok` actually writes in `\0` characters at the end of each token, which will make it a pain when you try to write this back to a file. Another thing to note; because you don't know how many digits your new number might have, you may have to resize the buffer to compensate. The function signature assumes this is done, and returns a number representing how many characters were added or removed (if any).

My general approach is to iterate through each character looking for newlines. Each time you've found one, check to see if it is the correct line, if it is, get the value, determine whether you need to resize the buffer and do so if necessary. Once that has been done, change the value.

```
int changeLineValue(char** buffer, size_t size, char* identifier, int newValue) 
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(buffer[i] == '\n' && isCorrectLine(*buffer, size, i)) {
           int oldVal = getCurrentValue(*buffer, size, i);
           int resize = getDigitsDifference(oldVal, value);
           if(resize != 0) {
              resizeBuffer(buffer, resize);
           }
           modifyValueInPosition(buffer, fl_size, i, value);
           return resize;
        }
    }
}
```

Note; because of the way that the C language works, `isCorrectLine(...)` will only be called if `buffer[i] == \n` evaluates to true. This is called [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Obviously the code above calls a couple of functions that have not yet been created, so part of your task will be to implement them. Note that the second parameter which has been passed `fl_size` is defined as `size_t` not `long` even though `fl_size` is a long. You should change this variable to `size_t`.

Below I have provided the function signatures. Since you are trying to learn C, I am not going to implement them for you.

This function will be called each time a newwline is encountered, with 'index' set to the position of that newline. It should return a 0 if the identifier is not found at this position or a 1 if it HAS beenfound at this position. Do not change anything in the buffer at this point

```
int isCorrectLine(char* buffer, char* identifier, size_t size, int index) {
}
```

This function should iterate along the line and return the number before the next newline character ('\n')

```
int getCurrentValue(char* buffer, size_t fl_size, i) {
}
```

This number should return the difference between how many digits each number has. E.g. 1 = 1 digit, 324 = 3 digits so 3 - 1 = 2

```
int digitsDifference(int old, int new) {
}
```

This function takes a *double pointer* (`char**`) and reallocates the memory with a larger or smaller buffer to take into account the different number of digits if required.

```
void resizeBuffer(char** buffer, int resize) {
    *buffer = // This is how you change the original pointer. Line is still incomplete 
}
```

Now the buffer is the correct size, you can go ahead and change the value in the buffer. Again, this function is passed in the position of the newline before the correct line, so you need to iterate along the line, change the values in position. If you find yourself overwriting a newline character (because the new number is longer), you might need to move all of the characters after this value along

```
int modifyValueInPosition(char* buffer, size_t fl_size, int index) {
}
```

## Writing to file

Once you have changed the original buffer, writing it back to file is fairly easy. Your main function should look something like this now

```
int main() {
    // ...code that gets buffer from file. Note, make sure you close the file handle
    // afterwards it isn't good practise to leave a file handle open
    
    fl_size += changeLineValue(buffer, fl_size, identifier, newValue);
    
    // ...Reopen file handle as you did before ...

    fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), fl_size, fileHandle);

    // ...Close file handle...
}
```

Comment: thank you so much fr the indepth illustration. i shall look into it and apply it in my solution